# Polyglossia and Verbatim problem

Tags: fonts, verbatim, polyglossia

After having some hyphenation problems with my text (in greek and english) I changed some of my packages. In the beggining I was using:

```
  \usepackage{mathspec} 
  \usepackage{xgreek}
  \usepackage{xunicode}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setallmainfonts[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
  \setallsansfonts[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
  \setallmonofonts[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
```

After doing some search I modified those to get correct hyphenation. After doing so in a small sample text, I am trying to change the packages of my original text to the ones used in my sample, in order to get finally the correct hyphenation. However at some point I get:

> Package polyglossia error: The current Roman Font does not contain the Greek Script.
>
> Line 242: \begin{verbatim}

The packages I use are the following:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[Greek,Latin]{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\setTransitionsForGreek{\selectlanguage{greek}}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: You have to define also `\greekfonttt`. I would never use `ucharclasses` for interspersing English in Greek; you risk *many* unexpected results.

Comment: So what would you recommend instead? Apart the strategy when you define a command for change language and then you put the language X block in it, like \en{I am Jonathan} \gr{Είμαι ο Γιάννης}

Comment: The default language is Greek; just define `\en` for  English snippets: `\newcommand{\en}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}` and use the provided environments to switch languages for longer passages in English (and maybe `\gr` for inserting Greek snippets in English text). *Marking* the code is always better. One problem you can run into is exactly that `\verb` text may not be typeset in the mono font.

Comment: @egreg Make that an answer, please.

Answer (score 4):

Verbatim text uses the font defined with `\setmonofont` (or the default Latin Modern Typewriter font).

However, when the Greek language is active, Polyglossia makes XeLaTeX look whether the font has the GRK feature and, if that's not available, it looks whether a font family under the name `\greekfonttt` has been defined. Thus

```
\newfontfamily{\greekfonttt}{FreeMono}
```

(use your preferred monospaced font) should do.

I wouldn't use `ucharclasses` for switching automatically from English to Greek and conversely: this will fill your auxiliary files with `\select@language` declarations *and* won't ensure that a monospaced font is used in `verbatim`. Rather prefer the standard method of confining language switches with explicit `\selectlanguage` commands (not recommended), `otherlanguage`, `otherlanguage*` or `\foreignlanguage`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Have a question about your remark: Why not use `ucharclasses` for switching automatically from English to <other language> and back? It seems easier than explicitly writing `\textsanskrit` (or whatever) at each place the other language is used.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I think that the last paragraph explains it

Comment: Thanks, I understand the issue with `verbatim`: what is not clear to me is whether, in case there is no `verbatim` used in the document (and thus no need for a monospaced font), it is still the case that "this will fill your auxiliary files with `\select@language` declarations" has any negative consequences that would discourage using `ucharclasses` to switch language automatically.